# Sending the data as attachment in mail using JAVA API of ElasticSearch Watcher

Tags: java, elasticsearch, email-attachments, elasticsearch-watcher

I want to attach the JSON data to the mail which is sent by ElasticSearch Watcher. 
I know how to do it through REST APIs but don't know how to do it through JAVA API.

Till now I have this :

```
EmailTemplate.Builder emailBuilder = EmailTemplate.builder();
emailBuilder.to(reqAlert.getEmail());
emailBuilder.subject(reqAlert.getSubject());
emailBuilder.textBody(reqAlert.getBody());
```

I am following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/2.2/api-java.html) for reference. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.elasticsearch.watcher.actions.email.DataAttachment;
import org.elasticsearch.watcher.actions.email.service.Attachment;

...

Map<String, Object> data = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>of("key", "value");
Attachment attachment = DataAttachment.JSON.create(data);
emailBuilder.attach(attachment);
```

Comment: attach function is not available for emailBuilder. Because It is showing The method attach is undefined for EmailTemplate.Builder

Comment: What Watcher version is this?

Comment: The watcher version is 2.2.0

Comment: Can you help on this?

Comment: Or if possible, Can we put the input payload in the body text itself. ?